# After pasting the following code, my browser crashed. Why?

Tags: javascript, browser, crash

After pasting the following code, my browser crashed. I have absolutely no idea why. I am a new to Javascript.

Here is my code:

```
var randarray = new Array();
var l = 0;
var flag;
var numofpost = 5;

function randomposts(json) {
    var total = parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t, 10);
    for (i = 0; i < numofpost;) {
        flag = 0;
        randarray.length = numofpost;
        l = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
        for (j in randarray) {
            if (l == randarray[j]) {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0 && l != 0) {
            randarray[i++] = l;
        }
    }
    document.write('<ul class="rp-menu">');
    for (n in randarray) {
        var p = randarray[n];
        var entry = json.feed.entry[p - 1];
        for (k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                var item = "<li>" + "<a href=" + entry.link[k].href + ">" + entry.title.$t + "</a></li>";
                document.write(item);
            }
        }
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the FAQ on how to ask good questions. "Pls solve this issue and give me right code" is not a good question, we expect you to debug your code, an **you explain** what went wrong, and what you tried to fix it.

Comment: Also, when asking for help with code, please take the time to format your code readably. There are **lots** of formatting aids clearly available on the Ask a Question page. I've run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ for you on this occasion.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Sorry, I started editing before you and posted it after you and only realized what happened afterwards. Sorry :)

Comment: If your intent is to hold a number of unique random number in a given range in an Array, there are better ways to do it. I'm guessing your array length (`numofpost`) is larger than the range of possible numbers (`0-total`), so you run out of unique numbers to put in the array, causing the infinite loop.

Comment: @monster Hello brother, I am very new in javascript. Could you edit my all code and give me right code so that i can use in my template. Pls brother give me right code.

Answer (score 2):

The increment of `i` in your first `for` loop is behind a condition, so if it never resolves to `true`, you'll have an infinite loop

Comment: @monster hello brother, could you tell me how to solve this? I am new in javascript.

Comment: @Noxdo: It has nothing to do with JavaScript, it has to do with logic. Your loop will continue until `i` is equal to or greater than `numpost`. If there is any iteration of the loop prior to that where you never increment ("add to") `i`, the loop will just repeat forever. So always increment `i`.

Comment: @Noxdo: Well your condition is `if (flag == 0 && l != 0) {`, which means that the only way for `i` to increment is if `flag` is `0` and `l` is not `0`. It seems that when `l` is set and found in `randarray`, `flag` is also set to the same value, so they won't  have the same value.